# Compile Compose multiplatform project to EXE

Tags: macos, window, exe, compose-multiplatform

I am trying Compose Multiplatform example project on my Macbook. When I call  `./gradlew :createDistributable` I see only MacOS executable in `/build/compose/binaries/main/` directory.
Is it possible to create Windows executable (*.exe) on Macbook?

Upd.:

my `build.gradle.kts` file

```
...
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Deb, TargetFormat.Exe)
            packageName = "HelloComposeMultiplatform"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            windows {
                packageVersion = "1.0.0"
                msiPackageVersion = "1.0.0"
                exePackageVersion = "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md#basic-usage) there is no cross-compilation support at the moment. So it's not possible.

> There is no cross-compilation support available at the moment, so the
> formats can only be built using the specific OS (e.g. to build .dmg
> you have to use macOS). Tasks that are not compatible with the current
> OS are skipped by default.

For example for creating Windows installers is used [Wix toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) available for Windows only.